# Could we call web behaviour programming to javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I recently develop a web application that uses a lot of javascript code and I face how to ***design*** and code it. So, I realized that javascript is focused on how some html items behave on the web page and not simple functions or methods that makes easy changes to UI.

Talking about web design, javascript could be considered as a web behaviour programming?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd rather describe JavaScript as [duct-tape programming](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html) for the web, for every time you say:

> Oh no, I can't do this within the
>   current limitations of HTML/CSS/my
>   development framework - let's use
>   JavaScript!

Comment: +1 so true. Still, we need to love our JavaScript. Were would we be without it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are telling a computer to do something, based on semantic and conditions, I'd consider it to be programming. But I guess that's always slightly subjective.

I'm using JavaScript/ECMAscript in one of my projects (not a web project) - and the JavaScript objects call the native C++ API in the background. So I guess that counts as programming; as you are actually controlling the C++ APIs in the background, but at a higher level of abstraction.